# custom war tasks and applying custom resources within Gradle

Tags: gradle

i want to have dynamic WAR tasks based on customer configuration. I created an array with the configuration names and tried to apply custom behavior as so:

```
ext.customerBuilds = ['customer1', 'customer2', 'customer3']

ext.customerBuilds.eachWithIndex() {
    obj, i ->
        task "dist_${obj}" (type:War) << {
            from "etc/customers/${obj}/deploy"
            println "I'm task number $i"
        }
};
```

This creates my three tasks like dist_customer1, etc. Now i want that gradle uses the normal resources under src/main/webapp AND also my customer based ones under etc/customers/XXXX/deploy as stated in the from property.

But it doesnt pick up any file in this folder.

What i am doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when setting up your War task ensure you don't accidently use the '<<' notation. 
'<<' is just a shortcut for 'Task#doLast'. so instead do:

```
ext.customerBuilds = ['customer1', 'customer2', 'customer3']

ext.customerBuilds.eachWithIndex() { obj, i ->
        task("dist_${obj}", type:War){
            from "etc/customers/${obj}/deploy"
            println "I'm task number $i"
        }
};
```

You can just add more from statements to pickup stuff from 'src/main/webapp'.

Comment: ups. i accidentally added my stuff into an execution block where it should have been in a configuration block as you stated, correct? Thanks.